# While loop not exiting program when using enter key

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am writing a main program file for a header and implementation file that I am working on for a school project. I have gotten my project to do everything I want it to except exit when the user hits the "return" button.

This is my program containing the main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    dateType date1(1, 6, 2000);
    dateType date2(15, 20, 2018);
    dateType date3(2, 30, 2019);
    dateType date4;

    date1.printDate();
    cout << endl;
    date2.printDate();
    cout << endl;
    date3.printDate();
    cout << endl;

    string test;

    int month, day, year;

    cout << "Enter month day year: " << endl;
    cin >> month >> day >> year;

    date4.setDate(month, day, year);
    date4.printDate();
    cout << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cout << "press any key to continue... ";

    while (getline(cin, test)) {
    if (test.empty()) 
        break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I i'm supposed to write an else statement for instances where users press keys other than enter. But i'm trying to get this part to work first.

How can I make this while loop execute properly?

Answer (score 1):

Your intent here is not clear but I will attempt to answer it anyway, first of all, for standard input to be passed into the program, the enter key has to be pressed, at least on Linux. Key press listeners aren't a thing in console applications unless an elaborate 3rd party library that spawns a worker thread that listens to key presses in the background is used.

All that remains is to test whether the entered input is empty or contains any data. I cannot see any problems with your code, I have created a tested, minified and verified example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "press any key to continue... ";

  string test;
  while (getline(cin, test)) {
    cout << test << test.length();  // For debugging purposes
    if (test.empty())
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want the program to wait for the user to enter a value to exit. Currently my program quits immediately after displaying "press any key to continue... " without actually waiting for the user to press a key.